# Executing two commands one after another in the same powershell session

Tags: powershell

For context, I’m trying to activate a virtual environment, and then run my python script from within that venv, all in one powershell session. I’m doing this in a .bat file that I will later start as a service (The whole point of this is to run main.py in the venv as a windows service)

I tried this:

`powershell -noexit -file C:\MyPythonProject\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1; python C:\MyPythonProject\main.py`

This doesn’t seem to work. Only the first command (to activate the venv) works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't do this as a powershell script and use invoke-command?

Comment: How would I do that? @Colyn1337

Comment: Replace `-File` with `-Command` and surround the rest in double quotes

Comment: You should definitely try what @Daniel said. If you are receiving an error message, you should be posting that in your question too.

Answer (score 0):

use `&` to chain commands:
`powershell -noexit -file C:\MyPythonProject\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 & python C:\MyPythonProject\main.py`

https://superuser.com/questions/1079403/how-to-run-multiple-commands-one-after-another-in-cmd/1079420